# Variable Variables for Array Key

Tags: php, json, syntax

Currently I am attempting to call a multidimensional array, using a string as a key or keys. I would like to use the following code, but I think the key is being interpreted as a string. Any solution?

```
$data= [];

$data['volvo'] = "nice whip";
$test = "['volvo']";

$data['drivers']['mike'] = "decent";
$test2 = "['drivers']['mike']";

echo $data$test;  // should read 'nice whip'
echo $data$test2; // should read 'decent'
```

Comment: Don't store the brackets in $test, just the key name. Then you can do `$cars[$test]`

Comment: I will edit the question reflect what i am trying to accomplish. The goal is to have multiple keys stored in the "test" variable, or just one.

Comment: Seems like odd code design to me. Why do you want to cram everything in $cars? "Multi level strings" like that doesn't work in PHP. You could merge the keys for both levels into one "combo" string key though, I guess. Would that work?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am creating a couple functions that manage a database-like array. I suppose I could create operation specific functions, or I could send a function an array of keys and iterate thru them, depending on how many variables exist sending them to a different case...

Comment: Eww, not case behemoths ;). What would happen the day the number of levels in your database/array changes? Would it be possible to pass the keys as an array then, instead of as strings?

Comment: ..or instead of changing $test variables you could create a single level database. The string keys will be fairly long, of course, but it is technically doable..

Comment: I would prefer to keep the database structure, this is for a version of my website template where mySql is not available or is not working.
Going the case route would be cumbersome, but I don't plan on going more than 5-10 levels deep...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a dynamic array access solution, you could also write a function, which does the actual array access like this:

```
function path($array, $path) {
    $path = is_array($path) ? $path : explode('.', $path);
    $current = $array;
    while (count($path)) {
        $seg = array_shift($path);
        if (!isset($current[$seg])) throw new Exception('Invalid path segment: ' . $seg);
        $current = $current[$seg];
    }
    return $current;
}
```

In your case, this would look like this

```
 echo path($data, 'volvo');
 echo path($data, 'drivers.mike');
```

or

```
 echo path($data, ['volvo']);
 echo path($data, ['drivers', 'mike']);
```

Comment: I just read this, haven't tested it yet but how does the comma work as separator in the second example?

Comment: Thats the way you define an array!?

Comment: I just cant wrap my head around how the code works recursively no matter how many dimensions deep I go, could you explain please?

Comment: You loop over the `$path` param and go a level deeper in each iteration. `$current` gets overwritten by the current path segment. In the first iteration, `$current` is the whole array, in the second iteration (after `drivers` segment), `$current` is only `['mike' => 'decent']`. Btw. you could transform each recursion into an loop, if you keep track of the current position

Answer (score 2):

You just use the variable (which should just be the string and not PHP syntax) in place of the string literal.

```
$cars = [];
$cars['volvo'] = 'nice whip';
$test = 'volvo';
echo $cars[$test];
```

Comment: I updated the question to reflect that I would like to use multiple keys within the test2 variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you can't pass multiple levels in one string like that. (If so, PHP would have to start looking for code fragments inside string array keys. And how would it know whether to interpret them as fragments and then split the string key up, or keep treating it as one string??)

## Alt 1

One solution is to change the structure of `$data`, and make it a single level array. Then you supply keys for all the levels needed to find your data, *joined together as a string*. You would of course need to find a separator that works in your case. If the keys are plain strings then something simple like underscore should work just fine. Also, this wouldn't change the structure of your database, just the way data is stored.

```
function getDbItem($keys) {
    // Use this to get the "old version" of the key back. (I.e it's the same data)
    $joinedKey = "['".implode("'],['", $keys)."']";

    $joinedKey = implode('_', $keys);
    return $data[$joinedKey];
}

// Example
$data = [
    'volvo' => 'nice whip',
    'drivers_mike' => 'decent'
];
var_dump(getDbItem(['drivers', 'mike'])); // string(6) "decent"
```

## Alt 2

Another way is to not change number of levels in `$data`, but simply traverse it using the keys passed in:

```
$tgt = $data;
foreach($keys as $key) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $tgt)) {
        $tgt = $tgt[$key];
    }
    else {
        // Non existing key. Handle properly.
    }
}

// Example
$keys = ['drivers', 'mike'];
// run the above code
var_dump($tgt); // string(6) "decent"
```